# Logistic regression: Estimation of marginal effects of predictors

Tags: logistic, linear-model, marginal-effect

I ran a logistic regression analysis with 12 independent variables (predictors). I heard that I could estimate the average marginal effects of these predictors using a linear regression model.

Could anyone help me understand this better?

What would the interpretation of the marginal effects be in this context?

Comment: I have never seen anything like this. Where did you hear this?

Comment: heard it at a conference.. see also the following link on p.35: https://www3.nd.edu/~rwilliam/stats/Margins01.pdf

Comment: That sounds like just an LPM (OLS with a binary outcome and robust std. errors). It is relatively more palatable if your predictors are categorical, though it has its defenders. There is an approximation that $\beta_{Logit} \approx 4\cdot \beta_{OLS}$ and $ME_{Logit} \approx \bar y \cdot (1-\bar y) \cdot \beta_{Logit}$, which you could use to get a crude approximation to the ME, but why would you in the days of modern software?

Comment: Thanks much! this is mainly because I only have SPSS and it doesn't seem to be part of their packages.. Would it take long to learn how to do this in STATA?

Comment: the first approximation by Dimitriy is the maximum marginal effect, and the second approximation is the marginal effect at mean values of the predictors. Especially the maximum marginal effect can deviate greatly from the average marginal effect.

Comment: @dav any change in software is an investment of your time and effort. I went through that change, I did not find that that hard, and I never regretted it. However, whether it is the right move for you depends on many factors: What do you want to use it for, how much have you already invested in SPSS, what software are potential collaborators using, etc. etc.

Comment: @MaartenBuis Can you explain why the first approximation is the max ME? I can see why ME$\le 0.25 \beta_{Logit}$ since $\Lambda(x'\beta)(1-\Lambda(x'\beta))\le 0.25$.

Comment: @dav If I remember correctly, SPPSS can predict $\hat p$ after a logit (or you can do it by hand easily), and for each person the $ME_i=\hat p_i (1-\hat p_i) \hat \beta_j$. You can take the average of that to get the AME. The standard errors are a bit more involved. In Stata, this is would be one line of code.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov if $\beta_{logit}\approx 4\cdot \beta_{OLS}$ then $\beta_{OLS} \approx \frac{1}{4}\beta_{logit}$, so you are approximating the linear probability model coefficient with the maximum marginal effect from the logit model, which often not a very good approximation.

Comment: @dav not long, Stata has very straightforward syntax for simple operations and I think there's a command that just does this out of the box